# How to use an argument/parameter name as a variable in a bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that allows connection to various servers, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
# list of servers
server1=10.10.10.10
server2=20.20.20.20
ssh ${$1}
```

And I'd like to run it like:

```
sh connect.sh server1
```

Can't figure out how to use the parameter's name as a variable. Arrays do not work on my Ubuntu too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use shell indirection like this:

```
x=5
y=x
echo ${!y}
5
```

For your script, following works:

```
#!/bin/bash
# list of servers
server1=10.10.10.10
server2=20.20.20.20

arg1="$1"
ssh ${!arg1}
```

Comment: +1 Really nice trick though it should be mentioned that this is bash only.

Comment: @helpermethod: Thanks and yes this is for BASH since question was tagged as BASH.

Comment: Hmm getting error "Bad substitution" here ssh ${!arg1}. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't run it `sh connect.sh server1` use it like `bash connect.sh server1`

Comment: @Lamy It seems you're using `sh` and not `bash`.

Comment: +1, but if indirect parameter expansion is available, arrays should be as well.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to switch on `$1`:

```
case "$1" in
  server1) ssh "$server1"
           ;;
  server2) ssh "$server2"
           ;;
  *) ssh "$server1" # when no parameter is passed default to server1
     ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# list of servers
server1=10.10.10.10
server2=20.20.20.20

if [ "$1" == "server1" ]; then 
    ssh $server1;
elif [ "$1" == "server2" ]; then 
    ssh $server2;
fi
```